# Linq way to find value in DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

May I ask someone to help me write this in LINQ,

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataColumn dcValue = new DataColumn();
            dcValue.ColumnName = "value";

            DataColumn dvDisplay = new DataColumn();
            dvDisplay.ColumnName = "display";

            DataColumn dvIsDefualt = new DataColumn();
            dvIsDefualt.ColumnName = "isDefalt";

            dt.Columns.Add(dcValue,int);
            dt.Columns.Add(dvDisplay,string);
            dt.Columns.Add(dvIsDefualt,bool);

            this.tipRacuna.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            this.tipRacuna.ValueMember = "value";
            this.tipRacuna.DisplayMember = "display";

            this.tipRacuna.SelectedValue =  findDefault(dt);//linq to find first value with default = true;    


        }
        private int findDefault(DataTable dtt)
            {
                int i= 0;

            foreach (DataRow  dr in dtt.Rows)
            {
                if (bool.Parse(dr["isDefalt"].ToString()))
                {
                    return int.Parse(dr["value"].ToString());
                }
            }
                return i;
            }
```

As I am getting more involved in C# and programming at all, I am getting more intersting in LINQ queries.
In begins I always skip LINQ taking argument as I know TSQL no needs for another Query language, but when I see how many lines of code i can save using LINQ i start learning it.

Comment: Since `isDefault` is a bool, why get the string value and parse it?  You can just cast it to a bool and be done.  Same thing with `value` as an int column.  Parsing isn't a super cheap operation, casting is.

Comment: @Servy Compiler wont let me to go on if I don't parse it to bool, I agree with you that I should try something before I asked for help. But my first step is to start finding way where I can use LINQ as option.

Comment: And you found one.  LINQ is an option here.  Now you have lost most of the possible learning opportunity of trying to figure it out because others have simply given you the full solution.  Had you worked at it for a while and still come up with nothing, then asking if it was even feasible or appropriate to use Linq here may have been useful, rather than asking for a solution.

Comment: As for the typing, as I said, cast it.  Don't just use the object that's returned because, as you said, it won't compile.  You need to **cast** it.  You can also use the `Field<>` property as shown in one of the answers.

Comment: @Servy perhaps I have bad and slow way to learn new things. Next time Ill try to solve problem first, I am here on SO for so long time and I know that is for most of us annoying this kind of questions

Comment: The question isn't the problem.  It's not that hard for other posters here to solve, it's the fact that giving you the code doesn't actually solve the purpose of the question, which is to help you learn LINQ.

Comment: Btw, Your code does not compile since there is no overloaded [DataColumnCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.add.aspx) that takes a DataColumn **and** and a type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that your DB columns are strongly-typed (best):

```
dtt.AsEnumerable().Where( dr => dr.Field<bool>("isDefault" ) )
    .Select( dr => dr.Field<int>( "value" ) ).FirstOrDefault();
```

With type conversion:

```
dtt.AsEnumerable().Where( dr => Convert.ToBoolean( dr["isDefault"] ) )
    .Select( dr => Convert.ToInt32( dr["value"] ) ).FirstOrDefault();
```

With parsing:

```
dtt.AsEnumerable().Where( dr => bool.Parse( dr["isDefault"].ToString() ) )
    .Select( dr => int.Parse( dr["value"].ToString() ) ).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Note that I have corrected the spelling of "isDefalt" to "isDefault".*

Comment: You're missing a `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: It looks like all the columns  in the DataTable are strings, i.e. it contains "true", "false", so `dr.Field<bool>` will fail. Ugly!

Comment: My bad - it is a bool column.

Comment: No, look at the column definitions, they are strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is roughly what you are after:

```
dtt.AsEnumerable()
   // find items that match your 'if' condition
   .Where(dr => bool.Parse(dr["isDefalt"].ToString()))
   // perform your int parse
   .Select(dr => int.Parse(dr["value"].ToString()))
   // take the first result
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The implementation above is effectively `FirstOrDefault`, not `First`.  It returns 0 if there is no default row.

Comment: @Servy yep, just spotted that. Fixed it :-)